# How to use JQ to merge corresponding elements of two arrays

Tags: json, jq

I have two arrays with the same amount of elements but with different keys/values. I want to integrate the key/value of the second array into the first for each index/position.

`1.json`

```
[    
    {
      "name": "xxx",
      "url": "yyy",
      "thumbnail": "nnn"
    },
    {
      "name": "bla bla",
      "url": "some-url",
      "thumbnail": "another-pic"
    }
]
```

`2.json`

```
[
    {
        "spotifyUrl": "first-spotify-url"
    },
    {
        "spotifyUrl": "second-spotify-url"
    }
]
```

The result I would like to achieve:

```
[    
    {
      "name": "xxx",
      "url": "yyy",
      "thumbnail": "nnn",
      "spotifyUrl": "first-spotify-url"
    },
    {
      "name": "bla bla",
      "url": "some-url",
      "thumbnail": "another-pic",
      "spotifyUrl": "second-spotify-url"
    }
]
```

I already tried different things but couldn't find the result I wanted. For example this one here:

```
jq -n '
  (input | map_values([.])) as $one
  | input as $two
  | reduce ($two|keys_unsorted[]) as $k2 ( $one;
      .[$k2] += [$two[$k2]] )
' 1.json 2.json
```

is almost what I want, except that the spotify-url is nested into its own object and looks like this:

```
[    
    {
      "name": "xxx",
      "url": "yyy",
      "thumbnail": "nnn"
    },
    {
      "spotifyUrl": "first-spotify-url"
    }
]
```

I appreciate any help and bet it's a lot simpler than I can think of. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a pretty good effort! but `transpose` is the key ingredient here

Answer (score 4):

It's easier than that.

```bash
jq -s 'transpose | map(add)' 1.json 2.json
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IaWBgWocbMk)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm. I already tried it with map, but the transpose in combination obviously did the trick.